# rate limiting traffic for internal ip (TC)

Tags: tc, strongswan, bandwidth-control

I have configured `ikev2` VPN on my server, but there is no tunnel interfaces like openvpn (tun0).

So actually, I can't limit the `ikev2` vpn speed using tc tool.

Example for traffic shapping of openvpn (tun0) below.

```
tc qdisc del dev tun0 root
tc qdisc add dev tun0 root handle 1: htb
tc class add dev tun0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1mbit ceil 1mbit
tc class add dev tun0 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 1mbit ceil 1mbit
tc qdisc add dev tun0 parent 1:10 sfq perturb 10
tc qdisc add dev tun0 parent 1:20 sfq perturb 10
tc filter add dev tun0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 50 u32 match ip src 10.24.26.1/32  flowid 1:10
```

Because `ikev2` doesn't have a tunnel interface I can't limit the internal IP speed using even tc.

Any idea on it?

I need to limit individual internal ip speed `10.24.26.1-10.24.26.255.`

Comment: Use iptables to mark your ESP packets then use a filter to act on the mark ?

Comment: can you show me some example?

Comment: If I could I would provide an answer.

Comment: Have you read the [Route-based VPN](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/RouteBasedVPN) article of StrongSwan? It includes information for legacy VTI devices and modern XFRM interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

ok guys, i already found out the way by limiting using internal address of ikev2

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.24.26.2 -j MARK --set-mark 6
iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.24.26.2 -j MARK --set-mark 6
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1mbit ceil 1mbit
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:10 sfq perturb 10
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 handle 6 fw flowid 1:10
```

Comment: https://linuxscriptshub.com/bandwidth-control-on-openvpn-using-tc-and-iptables-for-individual-user/

https://linuxscriptshub.com/bandwidth-control-on-ikev2-with-tc-and-iptables/

https://linuxscriptshub.com/bandwidth-rate-limiting-on-vpn-pptp-l2tp/

Comment: Great solution. This works, however, the entire VPN traffic is limited to 1mbit/s. This is not limiting the speed per connected user to 1mbit. Correct me if I'm wrong..